# Covergence test for a numerical integration

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, axis-labels

I'm trying to check for convergence using the midpoint method as a numerical method. I can get a table of data but I'm not sure how to graph it or add a log scale. Here is my code so far. Any help is much appreciated.

```
 from math import exp,pi
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 def midpoint(f,a,b,n):
     h=float( (b-a)/n)
     result=0
    for i in range(n):
       result+=f((a+ h/2.0)+ i*h)
     result*= h
     return result

 #g= lambda y: (y**3)/(exp(y)-1)
 g=lambda y: ((exp(-y)*y**3)/(1-exp(-y)))
 a=0
 b=1000
 print(    'n             midpoint')
 for i in range(1,20):
     n=2**i
     m=midpoint(g,a,b,n)
     print('%7d  %.16f' %(n,m))

 """r=(pi**4/15)
plt.plot(n,m,label="numberical")
plt.plot(n,r,label="analytical")
plt.xlabel('n')
plt.ylabel('intergral')
plt.legend()
plt.show()"""

 """plt.semilogx(n,m)
  plt.show()"""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to plot the approximation rather than error vs interval. Key changes to make are:

1) `n` and `m` should be array or list;
2) Since the exact result is a constant which corresponds to a horizontal line, it should be plotted from `(xmin, r)` to `(xmax, r)`;
3) Use `ax.set_xscale('log')` to get log scaled x axis.

The complete code is as follow. I made a few more changes, trying to use `numpy` to increase readability.

```
from math import exp,pi
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def midpoint(f,a,b,n):
    h = float((b - a) / n)
    result = 0
    for i in range(n):
        result += f((a + h / 2.0) + i * h)
    result *= h
    return result

g = lambda y: ((exp(-y) * y ** 3) / (1 - exp(-y)))
a = 0
b = 1000
n = 2 ** np.arange(1, 20)
f = np.vectorize(midpoint)
m = f(g, a, b, n)
r = (pi**4/15)

plt.plot(n, m, label="numberical")
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_ylim(auto=False)
xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
plt.plot([xmin, xmax], [r, r], label="analytical")
plt.xlabel('n')
plt.ylabel('intergral')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you this was super helpful. IM not really sure what you did to make the graph though. what is plt.gca()?

Comment: As described in the [document](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.gca), it is to "Get the current Axes instance on the current figure". I used it to give myself access to `xscale` and `ylim`.

Comment: Thank you. Im also trying to graph the percentage error as a log function. i kept most of the above nut tried changing the y axis with the percentage . Here is what i did got after the initial midpoint function.  i added perc=log((abs(f - r)/(r)))

plt.plot(n,perc). however im not sure how to make it a log and it keeps making an error.